# Optimize Entity Framework 6 and reducing round trips

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, t-sql, optimization

I've been using EF6 for about a year now and I really like it but as an experienced SQL Server programmer getting the best performance is of high interest.  I searched the net and see a lot about optimizations and minimizing round trips but I'm not finding the simple answer to a problem like this.  We use a data layer built solely around EF 6 against our SQL Server 2014 database.  We're embracing EF6 but I'm not happy with the performance so far.  I have more involved methods but let me just ask a simpler one such as in the sample below.

In the method below, I imagine this is round tripping and querying 5 times? I know I could create a stored procedure with output params and round trip once and maybe that is the right way to go about this?  How can I optimize this method so the result is returned in the most efficient and fastest way?

```
    public static DataInspection GetDataInspection(int userId)
    {
        using (var context = new DemoEntities())
        {
            var di = new DataInspection();

            di.TripCount = context.Trips.Count(x => x.userId == userId);
            di.DayCount = context.Days.Count(x => x.userId == userId);
            di.LegCount = context.Legs.Count(x => x.userId == userId);
            di.MinTripSequenceStart = context.Trips.Where(x => x.userId == userId).Min(y => y.seqStartTime);
            di.MaxTripSequenceEnd = context.Trips.Where(x => x.userId == userId).Max(y => y.seqEndTime);

            return di;
        }
    }
```

Here is a second method that returns data for a user.  I'd also like to optimize this method to minimize round trips and execute this method the fastest possible way.  There are no relations between these entities.

```
    public static UserData GetMetaData(int userId)
    {
        using (var context = new DemoEntities())
        {
            var cloudData = new DemoData();

            var aircraft = context.Aircraft.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var aircraftTypes = context.AircraftTypes.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var airlines = context.Airlines.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var airports = context.Airports.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var approaches = context.Approaches.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var approachesLegs = context.ApproachesLegs.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var binaries = context.BinaryCatalogs.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var crews = context.Crews.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var employmentEvents = context.EmploymentEvents.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var events = context.Events.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var hotels = context.Hotels.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var notes = context.Notes.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var payperiodevents = context.PayperiodEvents.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var payrollCategories = context.PayrollCategories.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var performance = context.Performances.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var positions = context.Positions.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var regOpsTypes = context.RegOperationTypes.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var usersettings = context.UserSettings.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
            var globalSettings = from p in context.GlobalSettings select p;

            cloudData.Aircraft = AircraftAssembler.ToDTOs(aircraft);
            cloudData.AircraftTypes = AircraftTypeAssembler.ToDTOs(aircraftTypes);
            cloudData.Airlines = AirlineAssembler.ToDTOs(airlines);
            cloudData.Airports = AirportAssembler.ToDTOs(airports);
            cloudData.Approaches = ApproachAssembler.ToDTOs(approaches);
            cloudData.ApproachesLegs = ApproachesLegAssembler.ToDTOs(approachesLegs);
            cloudData.Binaries = BinaryCatalogAssembler.ToDTOs(binaries);
            cloudData.Crews = CrewAssembler.ToDTOs(crews);
            cloudData.EmploymentEvents = EmploymentEventAssembler.ToDTOs(employmentEvents);
            cloudData.Events = EventAssembler.ToDTOs(events);
            cloudData.Hotels = HotelAssembler.ToDTOs(hotels);
            cloudData.Notes = NoteAssembler.ToDTOs(notes);
            cloudData.PayperiodEvents = PayperiodEventAssembler.ToDTOs(payperiodevents);
            cloudData.PayrollCategories = PayrollCategoryAssembler.ToDTOs(payrollCategories);
            cloudData.Performances = PerformanceAssembler.ToDTOs(performance);
            cloudData.Positions = PositionAssembler.ToDTOs(positions);
            cloudData.RegOperationTypes = RegOperationTypeAssembler.ToDTOs(regOpsTypes);
            cloudData.UserSettings = UserSettingAssembler.ToDTOs(usersettings);
            cloudData.GlobalSettings = GlobalSettingAssembler.ToDTOs(globalSettings);

            return cloudData;
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any tips on getting the absolute best performance out of Entity Framework 6 with VS 2013 C#.  I've seen companies use products such as NHibernate and have major performance issues and now that I'm using EF 6 in an larger scale way I too am seeing this which I don't believe either is a result of the product but instead the implementation and that's what I'm asking for help with here.

Comment: First, make sure that round-trips are actually causing your problem. Could be a badly tuned query or database, or CPU work in the web app. Look into Entity Framework future queries. I believe it is still not built-in but can be bolted on.

Comment: Also, this is a consequence of bad data modeling. What on earth (and in the sky) has an aircraft to do with a userId? With decently normalized data you would be able to fetch these data as object graphs by just a few efficient queries (maybe one).

Comment: @GertArnold We have a database that supports unlimited users, each user is represented by a userId PK INT.  In this example I'm pulling data for a specific user.  How do you suggest it be done?

Comment: "How do you suggest it be done". After changing the data model is how. A user that has everything is impossible. An airline has aircraft. A user doesn't. An aircraft has a crew, a user doesn't, etc, etc. If you can't (or won't) change the model your way is the only way, maybe tweaked into query packages (future queries) as usr suggests.

Comment: @GertArnold I think you'd have to understand our application to understand this design.  I appreciate your feedback but the model is as it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating with SQL Server 2014 Profiler observing the round trips but also the connection resets and study of various articles on optimizations, here is what I came up with.

1) Use AsNoTracking() for read only methods such as:

```
var aircraft = context.Aircraft.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.userId == userId);
```

2) Where queries will round trip, open the connection manually to keep it open by calling the code as shown below:

```
    using (var context = new DemoEntities())
    {
        var cloudData = new DemoData();
        context.Database.Connection.Open();

        var aircraft = context.Aircraft.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
        var aircraftTypes = context.AircraftTypes.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
        var airlines = context.Airlines.Where(x => x.userId == userId);
        //....rest of code here
    }
```

3) For the DataInspection method I could have used the connection open and then 5 round trips and been fine with it but I chose to use a stored procedure with output params to make one trip to the database and handle nulls per our needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data in one round trip by something like this:

```
var data = (from trip in context.Trips.Take(1)
            let TripCount = trip.Count(x => x.userId == userId)
            let DayCount = context.Days.Count(x => x.userId == userId)
            let LegCount = context.Legs.Count(x => x.userId == userId)
            let MinTripSequenceStart = trip.Where(x => x.userId == userId).Min(y => y.seqStartTime)
            let MaxTripSequenceEnd = trip.Where(x => x.userId == userId).Max(y => y.seqEndTime)
            select new {
                TripCount,
                DayCount,
                LegCount,
                MinTripSequenceStart,
                MaxTripSequenceEnd
            }).ToList();
```

and finally with automapper copy data to `DataInspection` class:

```
var dataInspection = data
            .Select(inspection => AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(inspection, inspection.GetType(), typeof(DataInspection)))
            .Select(di => di as DataInspection);
```

Comment: This executes count for *each* record in `Trips`. You could add `Take(1)`, but that makes it look like a hack even more.

Comment: @mo.esmp Thanks for the code tip, certainly an interesting way to go about it.  I think this would fail if there were no Trips for this user, i.e. a query against an empty database for a new user scenario. May have to use FirstOrDefault() instead?