# Reduce EF Round-trips on Inserts when some data fetch from the DB

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

**TL;DR**: Is there any way to reduce round-trips to the database from an EF app that needs to look up a few
things before doing an insert.

Situation: A .NET 7 EF WebAPI app running against a SQL database.  As a (very) minimal repro app, consider
this simplified appointments application:

- Three entity types: Meetings, People, Places
- Relationships:

  - Places can host multiple meetings
  - People can attend multiple meetings
  - Meeting have multiple people attend
- So, four tables in the database, Meeting, Person, Place and the Meeting-People join table
- All the tables have ID primary keys (and expected foreign keys / relationships).
- All three entity types have `string Name` properties that have a unique index

Everything is scaffolded using the `dotnet ef` tool in the standard fashion.

To do a Meeting insert, I want a JSON payload that looks like:

```
{
    "Name": "MyMeetingName",
    "PlaceName": "ThePlaceName",
    "StartTime": "2023-03-21T21:52:41.510Z",
    "OtherParameters": "Stuff",
    "ParticipantNames": [
        "Ferd Berfle",
        "John Q Public"
    ]
}
```

On the server, my code to do the insert looks like (with the payload deserialized into `meeting`)

```
var place = await _context.Places.Where(place => place.Name == meeting.PlaceName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var participants = await _context.People.Where(p => meeting.ParticipantNames.Contains(p.Name)).ToListAsync();
var newMeeting = new Meeting
{
    Name = meeting.Name,
    Place = place,
    StartTime = meeting.StartTime,
    Other = meeting.OtherParameters,
};
// add in the participants
foreach (var person in participants){
    newMeeting.Participants.Add(person);
}
_context.Meetings.Add(newMeeting);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
// cleanup and return
```

*(this is transcribed from a similar system with different names, sorry if I messed up)*

This all works.  But...

It makes three round-trips to the database (one to fetch the Place, one to fetch the Participants and
a third on `await SaveChangesAsync`).

My first try was to see if I could do the two fetches in a single round trip.  I tried this by capturing
the Tasks associated with the two fetches (async, without await) and then doing an `await WhenAll()` and
reading the `Task.Result`s. I can see two separate commands being executed (each with a duration) in the
debug output, so that didn't work.

It looks like this (not the accepted answer, the other one) might be an approach to allowing the two
fetches to be done in a single round-trip:
[Optimize Entity Framework 6 and reducing round trips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713393/optimize-entity-framework-6-and-reducing-round-trips)

But what I was really hoping was that there was a way to indicate that I wanted to do the two fetches
on the database server and have those queries *mixed in* with the insert somehow.  I'm quite
comfortable playing in `IQueryable` land and composing queries out of separate queryables when I'm doing
a GET, but I can't figure out how to mix a queryable into something that will eventually result in a
`SaveChanges`.

Am I stuck, or am I missing something?

***Update***: (2023-03-22 14:00 UTC, 09:00 CDT)

This is truly just a Minimal Example, not a real problem I'm trying to solve (in fact, it's a more-minimalized version of a reduced example of a problem).  I'm well versed in SQL script, so I know about transactions and stored procedures (and how to invoke a stored procedure from EF).  I also know the benefits of working with IDs instead of indexed strings.

My question was really about mixing `IQueryable`s with `SaveChangesAsync`.  It appears that my intuition in this regard is mostly correct (that it's not a real path to follow).  @StevePy's answer describing `DbContext.Attach` was enlightening though - thanks.

Comment: _"Is there any way to reduce round-trips to the database from an EF app that needs to look up a few things before doing an insert."_ - yes: move all of your logic into a `TRANSACTION` inside a `PROCEDURE` and invoke that from EF (or just any `SqlCommand`). EF is a fantastic ORM, but _all_ ORMs are unsuitable for high-volume work such as bulk/set-based and unconditional DML. (You can pass variadic data, such as your `participants`, into a `PROCEDURE` using a table-valued parameter, btw)

Comment: Why do you want to optimize this, and (how) do you want to handle errors (users posting non-existent places and such)?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Some of this is intellectual curiosity. Some of it is the result of years of pre-EF apps and SQL. I'm preparing internal training for teams moving to C# and EF and trying to make sure I understand what the edge cases are (to get ready for potential questions).

Comment: Also, while `SaveChangesAsync` will execute sql in batches, this may cause more than one round trip.

Answer (score 2):

The optimizations I can recommend is to ensure you are using indexed values. Given the creation of this data involves an association of an existing place and existing people, then this could be done via the respective PKs rather than the Names.  Names may be nice for reading JSON, but they are larger, and if not indexed, more expensive to query. They are also more expensive to index, and prone to issues like unique constraints, I.e. there are far, far more likely to be more than one "John Smith" in any given location.

Given a structure like:

```
{
    "Name": "MyMeetingName",
    "PlaceId": 16,
    "StartTime": "2023-03-21T21:52:41.510Z",
    "OtherParameters": "Stuff",
    "ParticipantIds": [
        25,
        19
    ]
}
```

You can query the data:

```
var place = await _context.Places.Single(place => place.Id == meeting.PlaceId);
var participants = await _context.People.Where(p => meeting.ParticipantIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToListAsync();
// consider checking that you have the correct number of participants:
// Assert.That(meeting.ParticipantIds.Count, Equals(participants.Count));

var newMeeting = new Meeting
{
    Name = meeting.Name,
    Place = place,
    StartTime = meeting.StartTime,
    Other = meeting.OtherParameters,
};
// add in the participants
foreach (var person in participants){
    newMeeting.Participants.Add(person);
}
_context.Meetings.Add(newMeeting);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Alternatively if you want to go for performance, and can trust the IDs (internal system, low risk of tampering, and handle any DB exceptions)

```
var place = await _context.Places.Local.SingleOrDefault(place => place.Id == meeting.PlaceId);
if (place == null)
{
    place = new Place{ Id = meeting.PlaceId };
    _context.Attach(place);
}

List<Person> participants = new List<Person>();
foreach(var personId in meeting.ParticipantIds)
{
    var person = _context.People.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == personId);
    if(person == null)
    {
       person = new Person { Id = personId };
       _context.Attach(person);
    }
    participants.Add(person);
}

var newMeeting = new Meeting
{
    Name = meeting.Name,
    Place = place,
    StartTime = meeting.StartTime,
    Other = meeting.OtherParameters,
};
// add in the participants
foreach (var person in participants){
    newMeeting.Participants.Add(person);
}
_context.Meetings.Add(newMeeting);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This looks in the Context local tracking cache for any request place or people that might be tracked, otherwise it creates a minimal placeholder and attaches it. This involves no round-trip to the DB and will keep EF happy to insert the new Meeting regardless of whether a place/person is tracked or not. The caveat of this approach though is that if any other code happens to request details about one of those entities that were stubbed in, they would receive a reference to the stub. (An entity with just the ID set) To avoid this risk you could track the stubbed entities and then detach them after the `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: Thanks, not what I was looking for (though I really didn't expect to find it).  Still, your description of `DbContext.Attach` was enlightening, and it's going into the _bag of tricks_ +1

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this being optimized further into 1 query to the database is by either registering a stored procedure inside the database and [then calling it using entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters) or [writing the whole command as a dynamic sql query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#dynamic-sql-and-parameters).